# gstreamer link different sink/source caps to plugin

Tags: gstreamer

I have plugin that works with raw video and can resize it during work.
This plugin have two (compatible) video inputs, and one video output.
Caps of input and output may be different

But when I try use different caps at sink and source it couldn't link.

Examples

This works good.

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=800,height=600 ! my_plugin name=t ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=800,height=600 ! fakesink videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=800,height=600 ! t.
```

But this isn't. [WARNING: erroneous pipeline: could not link t to fakesink0]

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=800,height=600 ! my_plugin make_small=1 name=t ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=750,height=600 ! fakesink videotestsrc ! video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=800,height=600 ! t.
```

I read `docs/design/draft-klass.txt` and looked to videoscale plugin description and changed my_plugin description like

```
Factory Details:
  ..
  Klass                    Mixer/Effect/Converter/Video/Scaler
  ..
```

But it still doesn't work. What i miss?

**Edit.** My problem occurred because of using `GST_PAD_SET_PROXY_CAPS()` for all sink/source pads. According to the [documentation](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstPad.html#GST-PAD-SET-PROXY-CAPS) this function  simplify event management and guarantee that those caps is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

using `GST_PAD_SET_PROXY_CAPS()` is an answer.

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question, but you should edit the answer so that it is complete enough to be easily useful to others who might have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for this. Is now ok?